# Changing nominal data - several names to 'Others'/

Tags: r

I am very new to R. I have a variable with 1000 different types of wines (nominal variable). Some more common one like Chardonnay etc are represented >100 times while there are several which are only present one or two times in the variable. These combined total up to around 400 of the total 1000 wine types. I want to rename all of these different, rare wines types to 'Others', without having to type and rename each individual wines.
Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: The [forcasts::fct_lump](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_lump.html) function might help

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks a lot! This was really helpful. Really appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table` to count the frequency of occurrence of each wine and if it is less than `n` then replace it with `"Other"`. If you have a character vector, you can do

```
n <- 2
wine_data <- c('wine1','wine1', 'wine2', "wine1", "wine2", "wine3")
wine_data[wine_data %in% names(Filter(isTRUE, table(wine_data) <= n))] <- 'Other'
wine_data
#[1] "wine1" "wine1" "Other" "wine1" "Other" "Other"
```

If you have factors you need to add additional level to the vector first before replacing it.

```
wine_data <- factor(c('wine1','wine1', 'wine2', "wine1", "wine2", "wine3"))
levels(wine_data) <- c(levels(wine_data), "Other")
wine_data[wine_data %in% names(Filter(isTRUE, table(wine_data) <= n))] <- "Other"
droplevels(wine_data)
#[1] wine1 wine1 Other wine1 Other Other
#Levels: wine1 Other
```